# How to generate tag prefixes using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I wanted to generate the following using XmlSerializer :

```
<atom:link href="http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

So I tried to add a Namespace to my element :

```
[...]

    [XmlElement("link", Namespace="atom")]
    public AtomLink AtomLink { get; set; }

[...]
```

But the output is :

```
<link xmlns="atom" href="http://dallas.example.com/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

So what is the correct way to generate prefixed tags ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First off, the atom namespace is normally this:

```
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

In order to get your tags to use the `atom` namespace prefix, you need to mark your properties with it:

```
[XmlElement("link", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public AtomLink AtomLink { get; set; }
```

You also need tell the `XmlSerializer` to use it (thanks to @Marc Gravell):

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
xser.Serialize(Console.Out, new MyType(), ns);
```

Comment: Hi, if I am using => new XmlSyndicationContent(contentType, content, serializerXml); where I cannot establish the namespaces. What can I do? I want the content of the atom entry be with namespaces :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Xml Serialization and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes)

Comment: In fact I am already using this :                     XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, _rss, ns);
And it just adds xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" as an attribute to my root element ... but no prefix to my <link> tag