# How to make a custom TypeConverter for a given type with XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, typeconverter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Serialization and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes)
>   [XmlSerializer property converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963423/xmlserializer-property-converter)

The question is how to create a custom TypeConverter for a type such as Boolean when de/serializing Xml in C#?

```
<Root>
  <Flag>True</Flag>
</Root>
```

Currently this does not work because the value 'True' has a capital letter.  I want the TypeConverter to take care of converting value to a Boolean.

I know there are a couple ways to achieve this, but I need it as a general solution.

Comment: I'm not aware that `TypeConverter` has anything to do with XML Serialization. "True" is simply not a valid boolean value in XML. It would be a perfectly valid string, but it's not a boolean value.

Comment: The idea is that I want the value to be converted to a boolean value.  I want to use the converter to define how the string in XML can be converted to the bool value.

Edit:

I should define that I want to use the converter in multiple places in my serialization.