# Format DateTime for both XML and JSON response

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a dotnet core API in which i have a model that looks something like this:

```cs
class A {
  public DateTime time {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to keep the property `time` as a DateTime, but when sending the response I want to format it as a string with the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

My problem is that I need to return in either XML or JSON, depending og the header in my request.

So my question is; Without changing the type, how do I make the API return the property `time` in the format i want for both XML and JSON?

Comment: Perhaps you could give this a try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963423/xmlserializer-property-converter

Comment: The **clean** way is to define a DTO which will satisfy all the needs for the response. See https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/Application/Categories/Queries/GetCategoriesList/CategoryDto.cs

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The DTO was also my 2nd choice, I just hope there was something simpler i could do