# Deserialize DataTable to custom class using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, datatable, deserialization, xmlserializer

Is it possible to deserialize DataTable to custom Class? One of soap requests return DataTable in this format

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="geolocation" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="geolocation">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
     <geolocation diffgr:id="geolocation" msdata:rowOrder="0">
       <Latitude>48.8186</Latitude>
       <Longitude>28.4681</Longitude>
     </geolocation>
     ...
  </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I would like to deserialize it into an array of

```
public class Geolocation {
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}
```

using XmlSerializer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Geolocation[]))
var Geolocations = (Geolocation)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

Edit: I tried to do something like this:

```
public class Geolocation {
    [XmlElement("Latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

but this didnt work

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [aevitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318973/aevitas) and some more research I finally managed to do it, first write your service references like this

```
public class DataTable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "schema", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Schema Schema { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "diffgram", Namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1")]
    public Diffgram Diffgram { get; set; }
}

public class Schema
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Element Element { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "complexType", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public ComplexType ComplexType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexType
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "choice", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Choice Choice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sequence", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Sequence Sequence { get; set; }
}

public class Sequence
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Element[] Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Choice
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
    public Element Element { get; set; }
}

public classDiffgram
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NewDataSet", Namespace = "")]
    public NewDataSet NewDataSet { get; set; }
}

public class NewDataSet
{
    [XmlElement("geolocation")]
    public Geolocation[] Geolocations { get; set; }
}

public class Geolocation
{
    [XmlElement("Latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

And then just write

```
// Namespace url is optional
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable), "http://example.com");
DataTable dt = (DataTable)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Hi @almis, how you create the stream to deserialize? Thanks!

Comment: @dachibox stream is the response stream from httpwebrequest

Answer (score 0):

For the `XmlSerializer` to work, you will need a C# class that is properly decorated and matches the XML.

For example, Microsoft provides the following sample:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Address MyAddress;
}
public class Address
{
    public string FirstName;
}
```

For the following XML:

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Address>
        <FirstName>George</FirstName>
    </Address>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

So in your case, you'd declare a `NewDataSet` class containing a `Geolocation` object (or a collection thereof, if you expect to receive multiple) which contains a `Latitude` and `Longitude` double.

Make sure you decorate the relevant types properly (like you have in your sample), and deserialize it as you demonstrated in your question.

It should work that way.

Comment: but it starts with `diffgr:diffgram` how I can declare such class?

Comment: @Almis See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes) for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent with a array or List<> object

```css
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("Geolocation")]
        List<Geolocation> Geolocation { get; set; }
    }
    public class Geolocation
    {
        [XmlElement("Latitude")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Longitude")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```