# Sitemap image element

Tags: c#, xml, nsxmlelement

i have a class for build xml sitemap in c# , i use it in a mvc controller to generate sitemap :

```
public class Location
    {
        public enum eChangeFrequency
        {
            always,
            hourly,
            daily,
            weekly,
            monthly,
            yearly,
            never
        }

        [XmlElement("loc")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("changefreq")]
        public eChangeFrequency? ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeChangeFrequency() { return ChangeFrequency.HasValue; }

        [XmlElement("lastmod")]
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeLastModified() { return LastModified.HasValue; }

        [XmlElement("priority")]
        public double? Priority { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializePriority() { return Priority.HasValue; }

        [XmlElement("image")]
        public Image Image { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("image")]
    public class Image
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "loc")]
        public string UrlLocation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }
```

this is output , when i use it :

```
<url>
  <loc>http://...</loc>
  <priority>0.5</priority>
    <image>
      <loc>http://...</loc>
    </image>
</url>
```

but i want correct format , like this :

```
<url>
  <loc>http://...</loc>
  <priority>0.5</priority>
  <image:image>
    <image:loc>http://...</image:loc>
  </image:image>
</url>
```

i want to add this prefix to image element ,
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
  There is good example.
You should add  XmlSerializerNamespaces type property in your Image class and you should add string prefix and string namespace values.

I read this [XML Serialization and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes) .

```
[XmlType("image", Namespace = "http://flibble")]
public class Image
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "loc")]
    public string UrlLocation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "caption")]        
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

Usage must be as below.

```
Image mySelect = new Image();
        mySelect.Caption = "Caption";
        mySelect.Title = "Title";
        mySelect.UrlLocation = "www";

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("image", "http://flibble");
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Image));

        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, mySelect,ns);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , can you write the correct format of this property for this class , please ?

Answer (score 1):

i add it like this :

```
[XmlType("image")]
    public class Image
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "loc")]
        public string UrlLocation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces NameSpace
        {
            get
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("image", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1");
                return ns;
            }
            set { NameSpace = value; }
        }

    }
```

and this is output:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://...</loc>
  <priority>0.5</priority>
    <image xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
      <loc>http://...</loc>
    </image>
</url>
```