# How to ignore the prefix on the web api XML request

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Good Day Fellow Coders,

I'm working on a simple Web API (.NET CORE 2.0) that accepts XML request.

Controller:

```
Route("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [Route("List")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult List([FromBody]Body request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Katawan")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product", Namespace = "")]
    public ProductRequest ProductRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Request:
[image]

This works fine and able to see the the actual request when debugging, however we did some changes on the request. We added some namespace on the Body. See below Image

[image]

After we added the prefix 'x', the request is now always null. I would like to request for your help here. I've already did some research like adding a DataContract and DataMember Attribute and set the namespace to blank, still no luck.

**Update**

We added a namespace for `x` but still the same, we also added new prefix on the Product. This is now the final xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Katawan
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <v:Product>
        <ProductId>string</ProductId>
        <ProductDescription>string</ProductDescription>
    </v:Product>
</x:Katawan>
```

Comment: Is it the your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes

Comment: sorry, not namespace, but a prefix. Edited the post. Thank you

Comment: Your xml isn't valid. You need to add an xmlns attribute for the x alias.

Comment: Added but still the same.  the request is still null. Thanks

Comment: You need to define the xnamespace <x:Kataway xlmns:x="Enter URL here">

Comment: Added but still the same, we added new prefix on the Product. This is now the final xml.`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Katawan xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <v:Product>
    <ProductId>string</ProductId>
    <ProductDescription>string</ProductDescription>
  </v:Product>
</x:Katawan>`

Comment: Your updated XML is still not well-formed -- the namespace prefix `v:` now has no `xmlns:v="..."` definition.  For the difference between well-formed and valid XML, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document and http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24992&seqNum=8.  To make sure your XML is well-formed you can just upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ or test-parse it with [`XDocument.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532(v=vs.110).aspx).  The asp.net XML serializers will not deserialize ill-formed XML.

Comment: Also, can you include your XML as text rather than as an image?  For why see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace for your own XML format. That namespace is reserved for, well, xhtml. Anyway, after you added a namespace, did you update this to refer to that namespace: `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Product", Namespace = "")]` and this one: `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Katawan")]`