# C# XML serialization namespaces in XmlElement

Tags: c#, namespaces, element, xmlserializer

I'm trying to create a Peppol Invoice xml by using C# XmlSerializer.
This all works fine except for the namespaces.

The Peppol standard format has namespaces in the XmlRoot, but also in one of the XmlElements.

Xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardBusinessDocument xmlns="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
  <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>

    ...

  </StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
  <Invoice 
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
    xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

      ...
   </Invoice>
</StandardBusinessDocument>
```

If I add all namespaces with XmlSerializerNamespaces, all these namespaces are assigned to 'StandardBusinessDocument '

Code example:

```
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("cac", "aaa");
        ns.Add("cbc", "bbb");
        ns.Add("ccts", "ccc");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data, ns);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
```

Is there any way to add these namespaces to the Invoice XmlElement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Declaring those namespaces in a higher enclosing element shouldn't change the *information content* of the XML. If whatever is receiving this XML is properly written (i.e. uses XML tooling rather than manual string manipulations), it should accept it just the same.

Comment: The surrounding `StandardBusinessDocument` (SBD) should be parsed separately. The `Invoice` is an `xs:any` inside the SBD that should be treated independently.

Comment: It appears "duplicated" but is not.

target is do so something like 
<sample xmlns="sample">
<something />
<new_root xmlns:new="url:new:ns">
  <newns:item1>sample1</newns:item1>
</new_root>
</sample>

I got that problem in one of my projects and i did found a solution

What you need to do is in the "new_root" class add namespace declaration like this.

[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
public XmlSerializerNamespaces newns;)

and in your item1 and item2 classes decore to use your namespace like this

[XmlElement("item1", Namespace = "url:new:ns")]

Comment: StandardBusinessDocument is wrapper created by the transport layer when sending document through the network, please validate documents with relevant schemas during development otherwise your project is bound to fail, schemas can be found on github: https://github.com/OpenPEPPOL/peppol-bis-invoice-3/blob/master/structure/syntax/ubl-invoice.xml