# How to change prefix of a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, powershell, xml-parsing

How to transform this

```
<d xmlns='uri' xmlns:a='uri'>
    <a:c/>
    <c a:atr=':a:b:c:d:e:f:'/>
</d>
```

into this

```
<d xmlns='uri' xmlns:b='uri'>
    <b:c/>
    <c b:atr=':a:b:c:d:e:f:'/>
</d>
```

?

Is it even possible? Preferably with `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

If it's not possible with .Net, do you know what is it possible with?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusted with this API, but you should be able to use [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493) to replace the namespace:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"E:\input.xml");

// Find and remove the namespace
document.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "a").Remove();

// Add a new namespace with same uri and different prefix
document.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "b", "uri"));

document.Save(@"E:\output.xml");
```

When saving, `XDocument` regenerates the XML and should apply the new prefix as long as you keep the same uri.

Comment: Is it possible with System.Xml.XmlDocument ?

Comment: Because if `xmlns` is the same as `xmlns:a`, every node without a prefix will be prefixed with `b`(if `a` is changed to `b`).